# How to automatically refresh tabs in firefox quantum?

Tags: firefox, browser, web

I relied on the [reload every](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/) add on, but as with many extensions it does not work in Firefox >57.

Does anyone know of a replacement? Will there even be a refresh functionality in the web-extensions api?

Comment: It's certainly doable, with a page action + a content script. The question is whether anyone has done it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not aware of a replacement for this handy add-on at this time. However, you could achieve the same functionality using the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) or [Tampermonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/) addon and developing your own userscript according to your preference.

Compare [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484978/i-want-a-simple-greasemonkey-script-to-reload-the-page-every-minute) for the necessary details how to create such a userscript.